# A functor on Abelian varieties corresponding to this operation on Weil numbers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties, finite-fields

Let $A/\mathbb F_q$ be an abelian variety over a finite field with Weil numbers $q^{1/2}\alpha_1,\dots,q^{1/2}\alpha_n$.

1. Consider the numbers $q^{d/2}\alpha_1,\dots,q^{d/2}\alpha_n$. These are still conjugate Weil numbers and by Honda-Serre-Tate should correspond to an abelian variety $\tilde A/\mathbb F_{q^d}$. What is the relation between $\tilde A$ and $A$?
2. Consider the $nd$ numbers $\{q^{1/2}\alpha_i^{1/d}\}$. The Abelian variety $\tilde A'$ corresponding to these numbers is, I believe the Weil Restriction of $\tilde A$ from $\mathbb F_{q^d}$ to $\mathbb F_q$. Is there a direct relation between $\tilde A'$ and $A$?

In my particular case, I also have a $\mathbb Z[\zeta_{\ell^m}]$ action on $A$ which has dimension $\phi(\ell^m)$ for $\ell $ a a prime different from $q$, $m$ very large, $d = \ell$ and $\dim \tilde A = \ell\dim \tilde A'$. I don't know if this is relevant at all.

(Of course, Honda-Tate is only upto isogeny but I would be very happy if there was a functor upto isomorphism that picked out some canonical $\tilde A,\tilde A'$.)

Edit - An explanation of the terminology:

Weil numbers are algebraic integers that have absolute value $q^{w/2}$ under every complex embedding where $q$ is a prime power. The integer $w$ is denoted it's weight. They are interesting because the Riemann hypothesis shows that over a finite field $\mathbb F_q$, for any smooth variety $X$, the eigenvalues of the Frobenius on the etale cohomology $H^i(X,\mathbb Q_\ell)$ are Weil numbers of weight $i$.

In particular, since the cohomology of an Abelian variety is determined by $H^1$, the weight $1$ Weil numbers determine all the others.

Conversely, a theorem by Honda-(Serre-)Tate shows that any conjugacy class (under the Galois action) of Weil numbers of absolute value $q^{1/2}$ can be realized in the cohomology of an Abelian variety over $\mathbb F_q$.

Comment: This does not produce an abelian variety of the same dimension as $A$. The dimension in Honda-Serre-Tate (for simple abelian varieties)  is not simply the degree of the polynomial, as you can see when $q$ is a perfect square and $\alpha =1$.

Comment: Oh that's right!

Comment: I guess the question still makes sense modulo the dimension

Comment: @WillSawin Actually, given that the minimal dimension depends only on the q-valuation of (some products of) the roots being positive over $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$, I believe the dimension shouldn't change after all.

Comment: Where are you getting that? The formula here http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/vigregroup/vigre04/hondatate.pdf seems more complicated than that.

Comment: pg 64 https://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/curves.pdf

Comment: The formula depends on the $q$-adic valuation being an integer, not being nonzero.

Comment: Right, but since I am only multiplying by a power of $q$, the integrality shouldn't change. The first condition is positivity in integers if I am reading it right, but that shouldn't change either?

Comment: Over $\mathbb F_{q^d}$, it's the $q^d$-adic valuation, so the integrality does change.

Comment: Already for the simplest case of elliptic curves over a prime field and odd $d$, the situation seems pretty complicated: for the supersingular curves you can just take extension-of-scalars to $\mathbb{F}_{q^d}$, while for the ordinary curves the corresponding abelian varieties are of dimension $d$.

Comment: it would be great if this question was readable to a let us say hypothetical person who was an algebraic geometer but didn't know what Weil numbers or Honda-Serre-Tate were.

Comment: @VivekShende I added some explanations, let me know if anything is confusing.

Comment: Thanks!  Does the Honda-Tate assertion mean: exactly the list of eigenvalues on H^1, or among the list of eigenvalues?

Comment: Exactly the conjugacy class. It has to be a conjugacy class since the Frobenius eigenvalues satisfy a monic polynomial equation over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @VivekShende The subtlety we were discussing earlier is that sometimes the list of eigenvalues will involve each member of the conjugacy class repeated a certain number of times. This is done to make the Newton polygon of the characteristic polynomial with respect to the $q$-adic valuation integral.

Comment: If you fix a Newton strata where the $k$ is the gcd of the coordinates of the vertices with $d$, then this map takes abelian varieties of genus $g$ to abelian varieties of genus $gd/k$. From the formula for the dimension of the central leaf of the Newton stratum (which is relevant because our varieties are defined up to isogeny and the central leaf is the whole stratum up to isogeny), we can see that its dimension is multiplied by $d/k^2$ by this operation. It is unlikely that we will have a canonical map, except possibly if $k^2=d$.

Comment: @WillSawin well, the map could be something like, fixed locus in some space (canonically associated to the variety) of some automorphism, which then could have varying dimensions.